# Is there a denomination/sect of Christianity that believes that Jesus was the son of an angel?

Tags: angels, comparative-christianity, persons-of-the-trinity, monotheism, denomination

Rabbi Yosef Massas (1892–1974) writes in responsa *Mayim Chaim* vol. 2 (*Yoreh Deah* §108:2) that he spoke to a Christian (possibly Catholic) priest who claimed that they only worship the One God and that when they say that Jesus was a son of *Elohim* this means "angel" not "God". Accordingly, this sect believed that Jesus was a son of an angel, not son of God.

Does anybody know of a Christian denomination/sect which fits this description?

(Rabbi Massas lived in Morocco and in Algeria if that helps)

Comment: Mormonism believes something similar, though they do believe that he's the (spirit) son of God.

Comment: @nick012000 do you have a citation? As a member of the church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints, I don't believe Jesus is the son of an angel.

Comment: This must simply have been a misunderstanding. Most Christians don't even know Hebrew, and thus that אלהים was used of angels in the Hebrew Old Testament. Also, the New Testament was written in Greek and not Hebrew, so they would simply be making 'originals' out of nowhere. I highly doubt such a sect has ever existed, and if it did, 1) it was definitely not of Catholicism, and 2) would not be considered Christian by anyone living today or in any given century, including probably even Mormons, whom most Christians do not consider to be in fact Christian. Without weighing in on either way.

Answer (score 4):

Latter Day Saints refer to God the Eternal Father as Elohim, meaning God or gods, and to his Son Jesus Christ as Jehovah (YHWH of the Hebrew Bible): "Elohim is the literal Parent of our Lord and Savior Jesus Christ, and of the spirits of the human race."  They believe the premortal Jesus was born as a spirit son of Elohim before coming to earth.  Source: https://eom.byu.edu/index.php/God_the_Father

Elohim is nowhere described as an angel, but Latter Day Saints believe that Michael the Archangel (who is a created angel) became the man, Adam: “In his premortal and postmortal roles, he is known as Michael and as the archangel (D&C 29:26)... Latter-day scriptures attest that Adam is a son of God, that his physical body was created by the Gods in their own image and placed in the Garden of Eden.”  Source: https://eom.byu.edu/index.php/Adam

There may be a connection between Michael (a created archangel) who is supposed to have been given a human body and is Adam (the father of all humans) in that Jesus was born of a woman, Mary: “Centuries before her birth, Book of Mormon prophets referred to Mary by name in prophecies of her vital mission (Mosiah 3:8). Describing her as "most beautiful and fair above all other virgins" (1 Ne. 11:13-20) and a "precious and chosen vessel" (Alma 7:10), they prophesied that Mary would bear the Son of God and was therefore blessed above all other women. "We cannot but think that the Father would choose the greatest female spirit to be the mother of his Son, even as he chose the male spirit like unto him to be the Savior" (McConkie, p. 327).” Source: https://eom.byu.edu/index.php/Mary,_Mother_of_Jesus

From what I have read, the following is a summary (as best I am able to understand):

> Elohim is God the Eternal Father, Father in Heaven
>
> Elohim is the literal Parent of Jesus Christ, and of the spirits of the human race
>
> Father in Heaven is the director of creation and Father of the spirits of all mankind
>
> God the Eternal Father is Elohim, meaning God or gods, and to his Son Jesus Christ as Jehovah
>
> LDS identify Jehovah of the Old Testament (YHWH) as Jesus Christ
>
> LDS identify Michael (the archangel) as Adam, who came to earth
>
> Mary, the mother of Jesus, was once a spirit daughter of Elohim

The teachings of Joseph Smith and the beliefs of The Church of Jesus Christ of Latter Day Saints (to give them their full and official title) would have been available to scholars in Morocco and Algeria during the 1900’s.  I am not a member of this Church, and if I have inadvertently misrepresented their beliefs, I will apologise.

To my knowledge, no Christian denomination claims that Jesus was the son of an angel, although some claim Jesus is known in heaven as Michael the Archangel.

Comment: Good summary, Lesley.  +1.  In fact, for the Bible believing Christian, Jesus actually said that angels cannot procreate Matt 22:30, Mark 12:25.